# BlobCache.Secure.LoadImageFromUrl(url) is returning null

Tags: xamarin.ios

IBitmap servedImage = await BlobCache.Secure.LoadImageFromUrl(url);

While executing above statement I am getting null response. Please suggest.
Akavache version - 6.0.31

Comment: https://github.com/reactiveui/Akavache/issues/196 Refer to the similar issue.